# How can I force TeX to put a page number on the title and abstract pages?

Tags: numbering, titles, page-numbering

My University's guidelines for thesis layout are a bit annoying: I'm required to put a page number on the title page, and I can't work how. Any ideas? I've tried `\thispagestyle{plain}` to no avail (although it did work for the abstract).

I've found a few identical questions on SE, and they were given answers which didn't work for them (or me). The structure of the code is below, all I removed was text basically.

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{I want a 1 to appear at the bottom of this page [doesn't work]}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
I want a 2 to appear at the bottom of this page [works fine]
\end{abstract}
I want a 3 to appear at the bottom of this page [works fine]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `empty` page style - typically called when you issue `\maketitle` - to be equivalent to the `plain` page style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{I want a 1 to appear at the bottom of this page [works fine]}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain % 'empty' page style = 'plain' page style
\maketitle
\endgroup

\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
I want a 2 to appear at the bottom of this page [works fine]
\end{abstract}
I want a 3 to appear at the bottom of this page [works fine]
\end{document}
```

The scoping `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` allows the changes to be temporary, while [`\makeatletter` is required for using `@` in macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764).

Comment: That worked splendidly, I just wish I'd've asked the question 6 hours ago. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the page numbers are continuous?